# 構造体の子側のメソッドから親のフィールドを参照したい

Tags: go

「ディレクトリの中にある複数のファイル」を以下のような構造体で表しています。

```golang
type MyDirectory struct {
    Name string
    Files   []MyFile
}

type MyFile struct {
    Name string
}
```

上記の `MyFile` 構造体に、ディレクトリ名とファイル名とを連結したパスを取得するメソッドを持たせたいのですが、下記の `"?"` の部分で行き詰りました。

```golang
func (f *MyFile) path() string {
    return filepath.Join("?", f.Name)
}
```

どのような方法がありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

自己回答です。[類似の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918208/go-get-parent-struct)がありました。
子のフィールドに、親を参照するポインタを持たせる方法です。

```golang
type MyDirectory struct {
    Name  string
    Files []MyFile
}

type MyFile struct {
    Dir  *MyDirectory
    Name string
}

func (f *MyFile) path() string {
    return filepath.Join(f.Dir.Name, f.Name)
}

func main() {

    d := &MyDirectory{Name: "hoge"}
    f := MyFile{Dir: d, Name: "piyo.txt"}
    d.Files = append(d.Files, f)

    fmt.Println(f.path())   //=> hoge/piyo.txt

    d.Name = "fuga" 

    fmt.Println(f.path())   //=> fuga/piyo.txt
}
```